# how can I change my mobile stock from KitKat to lollipop mobile name HSL yuva y302

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

please help me to install the stock lollipop in my HSL phone because I have a problem in connection of 3G in my phone of KitKat phone .

Comment: Why don't you try troubleshooting your Kitkat?

Answer (score 1):

There is no lollipop rom available as far as I can tell. But I don't think they will ever release an update to Android 5.0 Lollipop because your phone runs on a mediatek processor which is known for low development activity. 
And a simple update to lollipop won't help you with your signal reception. You would have to flash a new modem which suits your country. 
So you can't do anything at this moment.

Comment: so sir for my network issue what I can do my mobile is not showing tower of 3g and if by chance tower comes and I start my data the it will not load anything so what to do please help

Comment: In general cases I would say that updating your modem might help but I can't find any available modem packages for your specific device. The best thing you can do at the moment is to contact your carrier and ask them for help. If that doesn't help you can try to replace your phone by the seller